# openui5 navigation between components

Tags: sapui5

I just want to use a login component, that handle the process for login, signin and recover password. I want to reuse this component in different openui5 applications.

What I cannot understand is how can I change from one component to another. I mean, once I authenticate in my login compomnent, and a controller validate authenticate the user, how can I change to another openui5 component.

I was trying to understand CrossApplicationNavigation in the AppNavSample but I cannot understand it. https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/ushell/demoapps/AppNavSample/localMinimalRenderer.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean SAPUI5 rather than OpenUI5? The control (and SDK) you reference is the Unified shell (ushell), which is a component of SAPUI5 only.

This control is the "Launchpad" for the SAP Fiori apps and is built from metadata of associated user roles from the backend SAP system which is why it is only part of SAPUI5 not OpenUI5.

If you do mean you want to use the Launchpad and are developing on a SAP system, you can find the documentation about "Cross-app navigation" here - http://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/09/4d968eb7c442208303427e82da92c9/content.htm?frameset=/en/09/4d968eb7c442208303427e82da92c9/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/e4/843b8c3d05411c83f58033bac7f072/plain.htm&node_id=187&show_children=true#jump187.

However, your example - a login form, then the main application - suggests this is actually not what you want to do and instead you want to navigate in within specific views of an app. Check out this tutorial in the OpenUI5 documentation on "Navigation and Routing" - https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/1b6dcd39a6a74f528b27ddb22f15af0d.html

Further, your example of login + app actually sounds like it might need to be handled outside of UI5 itself on the specific backend/application/web server that you are developing against. UI5 can provide the appropriate frontend though.